# After the end of slavery at the closure of the US civil war, what percentage of former slaves stayed at their previous workplaces?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, economy, slavery

Upon the abolition of slavery in the USA, there were suddenly millions of former slaves set free.  But they were left without an obvious workplace. On the other side, millions of jobs done previously by slaves were now without manpower.

I would guess that at least some slaves stayed as – now paid – employees of their former owners, while those who were brutally mistreated, or who hoped they could find better employment elsewhere, just left.

However, I don't know about the statistics. There are many detailed [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abolitionism_in_the_United_States) about the end of slavery in the US, discussing different futures of freed slaves (some getting their own farms, some migrating North, even a very few migrating to Africa), but no statistics are given.

Were those who stayed an insignificant number, the majority, or somewhere in-between?

Are there detailed statistics? Or if there aren't, can at least rough estimates be inferred? I'm referring to former slaves being in the direct employ of their former owners, so cases of getting the land they worked on as their own, don't count.

Comment: [Relevant reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forty_acres_and_a_mule) for your research.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy : I know about that project, but that doesn't answer how many stayed as employees of their former owners.

Comment: The vast majority of them stayed around insofar as I'm aware, but I unfortunately don't know the precise stat. As explained in the linked article though, northern states didn't want black migrants due to "fear of competition by black workers, as well as generalized racial prejudice". There's also more recent work that raised that about [a quarter of freed slaves died](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2012/jun/16/slavery-starvation-civil-war) between 1862 and 1870 from famine or illness. So whatever the precise stat you end up finding is, you'll need to consider whether that was factored in.

Comment: @LangLangC : just to make it clear: I'm in no way supporting slavery of any kind. What I wanted to express, that I assumed that those slaves who were treated exceptionally brutally by their owners, were beaten, flogged etc. didn't stay to work for them after they were freed. Do you have better expressions in mind to formulate this, to avoid misunderstandings?

Comment: I did some cursory googling, but couldn't find any readily available stats. The closest thing I found was [this piece by PBS](https://www.pbs.org/wnet/african-americans-many-rivers-to-cross/history/on-african-american-migrations/). Kansas was the most welcoming nearby state. Around 30k (out of 4M) former slaves moved there, which is epsilon. Migrations occurred later, during the [Great Migration(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Migration_(African_American)).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy : I also did a cursory googling without any useful results, this is why I asked the question in the first place. At this point even a Fermi estimation would be better than nothing, but I lack the numbers even for that.

Comment: Well, the Great Migration article I just linked to has a rather telling number FWIW: "In every U.S. Census prior to 1910, more than 90% of the African-American population lived in the American South." (Census data might indeed be the closest you'll get to an actual stat.)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy : but it doesn't say anything about how many of those 90% were employees of their former owners.

Comment: But the first article I linked to did in a sense. Most of the slaves had no choice but to work in the very same plantation they had been freed from. At times they even lived in the same slave pens.